# converting array of integers into string in C

Tags: c

int arr[]={2,54,87,9,132,6};
    I want side by side numbers are converted into single string  in C.

```
like 2, 54 ==>converted into 254

 87,9  ==>converted into 879

 132,6 ==>converted into 1326
```

Comment: use `sprintf`. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: And a `for` loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: confusing to use sprintf for iterating integers....so anyone gives the clear answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @sash some code showing what you've tried and a clear question as opposed to a statement just might warrant an answer

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i+=2) {
    char s1[20], s2[20];
    sprintf(s1, "%d", a[i]);
    sprintf(s2, "%d", a[i+1]);
    strcat(s1, s2);
}
```

Comment: It's just `sprintf(s1, "%d%d", a[i], a[i+1]);`

Comment: Then I should write the whole program for you, right? Probably stack overflow is not for that. @sash